# How to get the class of a field on a generic object when field is referenced by string name

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

I have a method that takes an object and a string (the string being the name of a field on the object). So i get the field from the object class and use the field.get(object) to get the value. But I want to cast that value to whatever class the field was defined as. Is there a way to do that cast without needing to use @suppressWarnings("unchecked")?

Here is my code. I shortened it to only use one object, but the original used a list of objects and returns a map with map-keys being the objects' values for the field and map-values being the object.

```
public static <T1,T2> T2 getFieldValue(T1 obj, String fieldName){
    Field field = null;
    T2 value = null;
    try {
        field = obj.getClass().getField( fieldName );
    } catch ( NoSuchFieldException e ) { ... }
    if ( field != null ){
        try {
            value = (T2)field.get(obj);  // <--- unchecked cast!!!
        } catch ( IllegalAccessException e ) { ... }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend passing in an argument for the class of `T2` if possible. By passing in the `Class<T2>` you are able to call the `cast` method. This method will throw a `ClassCastException` if the cast is invalid. This will also remove the unchecked warnings messages.

```
public static <T1, T2> T2 getFieldValue(T1 obj, String fieldName, Class<T2> cls) {
    Field field = null;
    T2 value = null;
    try {
        field = obj.getClass().getField(fieldName);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    }
    if (field != null) {
        try {
            value = cls.cast(field.get(obj));  // <---  no unchecked cast!!!
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: +1 for using `Class.cast()`, but -1 for the empty catch blocks. It would probably be good to catch something like `ReflectiveOperationException` and do something more useful with it, even if it's rethrowing it wrapped in an `IllegalArgumentException` or something.

Comment: It is true that the exceptions should be handled in someway; however, I left them empty as the original example also left them empty. The only difference is that I removed the "..." so that the code will compile.

Comment: `value = cls.cast(field.get(obj));` is not safe. The warning is just moved away and suppressed away. It gives a impression of safe code while it is not. I prefer an explicit cast with an explicit `@suppressWarnings` that conveys the unsafe side of the method.

Comment: Damn. This is  how i had written it at first and I felt like it had too many arguments. Oh well...  Also I left the exception handling out because it wasn't important to the question.

Comment: But isnt there a way to give the method a type argument like ``utilClass.<String>getFieldValue(object, "someString");``. I understand its just moving the argument to another place, but it seems easier for me to understand, this call will return a map with String keys.

Comment: @DragonAssassin i forgot to add  the @ so i dont know if you saw my next comment. Thank you, by the way, for the answer.

Comment: @davidxxx `Class.cast()` is as safe as possible. Downcasting can always result in an error. Using @SuppressWarnings and an explicit cast is a perfectly valid way. However, this method gives no clear notion that a `ClassCastException` can be thrown. The `Class.cast()` states clearing in JavaDoc that a `ClassCastException` can be thrown. This means the method is not safe at all times and tells you to explicitly what exception to catch if an error occurs.

Comment: @Julian I wish you could do `UtilClass.<String>getFieldValue(object, "name")`. However, java has type erasure so at runtime the class information is gone. This is why you explicitly pass the class object so you can use the information at runtime.

Comment: 1.ClassCastException is unchecked. So you have to read the whole method to detect it while @supresswarning is clearly visible. 2.Class.cast() is unsafe as at runtime it may throw ClassCastException. It is what unsafety  means and what safety  searches to solve. Unsafety doesn't mean that it will always fail, just it may fail.

Comment: Sorry if I give the impression to be a jerk. It is just that I dislike using this method in this way as it hides potential problem to developpers.

Comment: @davidxxx I completely agree with you that suppression is a valid option. However, when using suppress it is wrong to ignore the `ClassCastException`. It may be an unchecked exception, but it still needs to be handle. When all you say is suppress the warning, I say this wrong. The exception needs to be handle by doing one or more of these options 1) documenting in javadoc, 2) adding to throws, 3) catching the exception. I feel you can shoot your self in the foot easily with suppression and it should be used with extreme caution.

Comment: @davidxxx: The problem with suppressing the warning isn't that you might get an exception (and "unsafe" doesn't mean "an exception could be thrown"). The problem with suppressing the warning is that you might get [**heap pollution**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html#heap_pollution). `Class.cast()` guarantees that a `ClassCastException` will be thrown *instead* of heap pollution: thus it is strictly safer.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden 
" The problem with suppressing the warning is that you might get heap pollution"
1)  In the JDK 8 `Class.cast()` suppresses this warning.
2) Suppressing warnings for unchecked operations or not to do it has no incidence on heap pollution. Heap pollution refers to having objects referenced by a incompatible type. Not to Suppress warnings will not change this reality.
3) To avoid heap pollution when you use vars or generics, a single thing matters : doing a check before the cast. You can perform it without using `Class.cast()`

Comment: @davidxxx: If you don't have a type token, then you don't know what type to check the object against. `Class.cast()` checks the runtime type of the object against the type represented by the `Class` object, and throws `ClassCastException` if they don't match. This is exactly as safe as a cast to a specific type known at compile time. (Warnings in the *implementation* of `Class` are irrelevant here: we only care about the emergent behavior.) If you write a cast to a generic type, then the actual cast in the bytecode is to the erasure of the type, which for an unbounded type will always succeed.

Comment: @davidxxx: To elaborate, if you try to cast like `T2 t2 = (T2) object;` then the bytecode that gets emitted depends on what `T2` is. If it's a type parameter (as it is in the example code in the question) then the cast that gets emitted in the bytecode is a cast to the corresponding erasure. If the type parameter is unbounded then the erasure is just `Object` and thus the bytecode emitted is equivalent to `Object t2 = (Object) object;` which the JIT will elide entirely. If the actual type is not actually `T2` then you get heap pollution unless you have a reified representation of what `T2` is.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden You had not need to elaborate :) I agree with you about the instance class is mandatory to avoid heap pollution indeed.

The thing that really annoys me is you have no warning in the applicative code when you use `Class.cast()`.  As I said in my initial comment :  The warning is just moved away and suppressed away. It gives a impression of safe code while it is not since `ClassCassException` may occur.

Comment: @davidxxx: Are you arguing that every single cast that could potentially produce a `ClassCastException` should generate a warning that needs to be suppressed? That seems... extreme. Any narrowing cast could potentially produce an exception! That's certainly not the way Java behaves today. And you continue to use the terms "safe" and "unsafe" in a way that is at odds with how those terms are generally used in the industry.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden  I refer to type safety and not safety in terms of security of course. 
It is maybe extreme for you but personally I don't consider writing code that may rise `ClassCastException ` as normal situation. 
It should be avoided and when it is required, it should be visible and limited. `Class.cast()` disables the visibility. With Java when you use reflection you have to handle checked exceptions : NoSuchFieldException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException , etc... that is more much restrictive than warnings.  Don't you find it extreme ?